# I use long for 16 digit number but it gives overflow error

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    long num = 1234123412341234;

    printf("%li", num);
}
```

I don't understand why it gives overflow error i'm pretty sure long's range is much more longer than that. Long long works but long should work too right?

Comment: What are the symptoms you observe for "overflow error"? What makes you think that a `long` is sufficient for that number in your environment? What e.g. is `sizeof(long)` for you?

Comment: 16 digits makes me wonder: is this is a credit card number? If so, it isn't really a "number" but a _string_ of digits.

Comment: To find the size of `long` try: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(long));` It's typically 32-bits while `long long` is 64 bits.

Comment: It depends on your system. A 32-bit architecture would overflow. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Comment: @wejoey its 64-bit

Comment: @Chris it gives 4 but i think it should give 8 why tho?

Comment: `long` is not 64-bits. A `long` is only guaranteed to be at least 32-bits. It *may* be longer, but there's no guarantee that it *will* be longer. On your system, a `long` is 32-bits.

Comment: @user3386109 but why? my system is 64-bits, tho it using only half of it, how can i fix?

Comment: @AlperTangil You fix it by using `long long`, or `int64_t` from `<stdint.h>`

Comment: @WeatherVane On my older pc it was using 64-bit what changed? and is there a way i can make it use 64?

Comment: [Rewritten]. MSVC uses 32-bit `long` even with the 64-bit compiler – the C Standard allows it. The bit size is more related to *pointers* than integers.

Comment: Then your older PC compilation wasn't compiling with MSVC.

Comment: Using types like `int64_t` is an excellent way to avoid this kind of confusion.

Comment: @AlperTangil If you need 64 bits, do not use `long`.   That's not what it's for. Type `long` *might* be 64 bits (and it is on e.g. x86_64 under Linux), but it is 32 bits on others, e.g. MSVC.

Comment: In C, type `int` is guaranteed to be at least 16 bits (but it might be more, and indeed 32 is quite popular).  Similarly, type `long` is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits (but it might be more, and indeed 64 is popular in some circles).

Comment: @AlperTangil "my system is 64-bits," is irrelevant.  The _compiler_ (and the C spec.) selects `long` range and you compiler uses a 32-bit `long`.

Answer (score 2):

A `long` is only guaranteed to be large enough to cover the range [−2,147,483,647, +2,147,483,647]. That's not even ten digits.

A `long long` is guaranteed to be large enough to cover the range [−9,223,372,036,854,775,807, +9,223,372,036,854,775,807]. This would do the trick.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    long long num = 1234123412341234LL;
    printf( "%lli\n", num );
}
```

You could also use `int64_t` or `uint64_t`.

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    uint64_t num = 1234123412341234LL;
    printf( "%" PRIu64 "\n", num );
}
```

[Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)